# Xorg: 800x600 resolution, can't use proprietary Nvidia driver, can't change keyboard layout

Tags: linux, drivers, resolution, arch-linux, xorg

Everything has been working well initially, but after a usual reboot my screen resolution is now forced to 800x600 and, I'm not sure if it's related, but I can't switch my keyboard layout anymore (it is set as a "setxkbmap ... -option lalt_lshift_toggle" command in my xinitrc). I'm using Arch Linux and I have nvidia and nvidia-utils packages installed, but apparently Xorg ignores this driver and uses nouveau/mesa instead.

Xorg log: https://pastebin.com/9DVKMqHR

Some terminal output that may also be useful: https://pastebin.com/EnLi5wdn

Comment: Have you run "nvidia-xconfig"?  https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas That solved the resolution and keyboard issues! It seems that my X configuration file was corrupted somehow. Although, something is still a bit off. My picom was working correctly before, now it outputs this:
[ 05/11/2022 00:51:10.697 vsync_init ERROR ] No supported vsync method found for this backend
[ 05/11/2022 00:51:10.697 session_init FATAL ERROR ] Failed to initialize the backend

Comment: AWESOME! :) Glad it helped!

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I've just realized that it's not completely solved, I updated the comment

Comment: Follow the rest of the guide on the page I included.  If you write yourself up an answer using the information I gave you, you can get some points.. (hint).  You have to wait a day to vote for your own answer.. but then you will get the points for it.